# Activity get destroyed when clicking his push notification

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I have an Activity, which has a fragment. In that fragment, I launch a service witch I need to do some stuff in the background. When some condition come to true in the service, I create a push notification, where i specify to reopen the activity (and load the fragment) when the notification is clicked.

The problem is that when i click the notification, the activity is destroyed and recreated again, and on the `onDestroy` method of the activity, I shut down the service (i want to kill it when the user close the app), so the service is no more running anymore.

How can i prevent the activity to be destroyed and recreated but simply resumed (like moving my self through the multitasking)?

How i create the notification:

```
            val intent = Intent(context, SplashScreenActivity::class.java)
        
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
                ApplicationServices.instance.applicationContext,
                channelId
            )
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
``
```

Comment: please refer to this link: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation

Comment: doesn't work, same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        // Activity Intent
        val intent = Intent(context, SplashScreenActivity::class.java).apply {
            // Note: Add flag(s) for Activity here
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        }

        // Pending Intent 
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            // Note: Use a non-zero positive Integer here, it's good practice ;-)
            System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(),
            intent,
            // Note: Add flag(s) for Pending Intent here
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        // Notification Builder
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
            ApplicationServices.instance.applicationContext,
            channelId
        )
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            // Using Pending Intent
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
```